# RTF Datawindow and RTF Control Content how to find the text by color, Font name?

Tags: powerbuilder

i stored the RTF file format in my ASA database.

How to select the content by using the color or Font name, Alignment.
for ex:

i have a content it has 100 lines with formatted text in between it contains the text which is in blue color, i need to select dynamically by giving the color "blue"

is it possible?

Comment: Which version of Powerbuilder are you using?  There are changes to RTF functionality in 10.5 and 11.5

Comment: i am using PowerBuilder 10.2.0 Build 7516

Comment: i tried through the rtf code and selected that related text and found it. it shows the duplicate text too, so if search like that we need to change/rewrite that rtf code then only it will be possible to select/Highlight that particular formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RTF, you have a colour table at the top which defines all the colours used.

With only blue defined, it will look something like this:

```
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}
```

Then in the actual text, you have `\cf1` to change to the first defined colour, and `\cf0` to change back to black, like this:

```
some black text\par
\cf1 this is blue text\cf0\par
more black text\par
```

(`\par` means  paragraph)